# Is hashing and salting required for signing up an user at firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

While signing up an user to firebase authentication, does firebase hash the password? Or do we need to first hash it manually by ourselves?

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that if firebase is offering a password based authentication method, the passwords will be properly stored.

Comment: Hey @Spandan, did my post answered this original question?

Comment: Yes I am going to mark it as the answer. But could you please vote my question please.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does hash passwords using a modified version of scrypt. More details can be found [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/scrypt/).